# ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, npm, gulp, aspnetboilerplate

In ASP.NET Zero 5.x, `npm run create-bundles` fails.

I am building a licensed project on the ASP.NET Zero's ASP.NET Core MVC + jQuery base solution, based on ASP.NET Boilerplate framework.  This is not a new/mint project, but an existing project that has been built and ran successfully in the past.

I have followed the [Getting started guide](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/latest/Getting-Started-Core) to ensure that I install the following:

- nodejs (v10.15.3) + npm (v6.4.1)
- gulp - ensured I installed it globally (cli version 2.0.1 local version 3.9.1)
- yarn (v1.13.0)
- bundler & minifier Visual Studio extension (latest)

I then ran `yarn` (twice - the first time around I received an error message), as per the guide.

Trying to run `npm run create-bundles` gives me the following error message:

It seems that none of my minified JavaScript files are generate

What can I do for `npm run create-bundles` to run successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - nodejs (v10.15.3) ...
> - gulp ... 3.9.1

It is an issue with gulp.js 3.9.1 on Node.js 10.14.2+. <sup>[1](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985#issuecomment-447241752)</sup>

These are your options, in order of recommendation:

1. Upgrade `gulp`: `npm install gulp@^4` <sup>[1](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985#issuecomment-447241752)</sup> — for ASP.NET Zero, upgrade to ASP.NET Zero 6.3.1+.
2. Install a specific version of `natives`: `npm install natives@1.1.6` <sup>[2](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246#issuecomment-435646661)</sup>
3. Downgrade to [Node.js 10.14.1](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.14.1/) <sup>[3](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985#issuecomment-449124867)</sup>

#### References

1. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985#issuecomment-447241752
2. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2246#issuecomment-435646661
3. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24985#issuecomment-449124867

Answer (score 2):

Just Update gulp version into 3.9.1 and this version support Node.js lastest version.

```
npm install gulp@3.9.1
```